# Setting Resized bitmap file to an MFC Picture Control

Tags: c++, mfc

Is there an easier way to do it than this, and if this is the only way, are there any potential memory leaks here?

```
    CImage img1;
            int dimx = 100, dimy = 100;
    img1.Load(filename);
    //filename = path on local system to the bitmap

    CDC *screenDC = GetDC();
    CDC *pMDC = new CDC;
    pMDC->CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);

    CBitmap *pb = new CBitmap;
    pb->CreateCompatibleBitmap(screenDC, dimx, dimy);

    CBitmap *pob = pMDC->SelectObject(pb);
    pMDC->SetStretchBltMode(HALFTONE);
    img1.StretchBlt(pMDC->m_hDC,0, 0, dimx, dimy, 0, 0, img1.GetWidth(), img1.GetHeight(), SRCCOPY);
    pMDC->SelectObject(pob);

    CImage new_image;
    new_image.Attach((HBITMAP)(*pb));
    //
    m_pictureCtrl.SetBitmap(new_image.Detach());
    ReleaseDC(screenDC);
```

Comment: In case anyone else finds this and is looking to set an image, but doesn't need resizing, use `((CStatic*)GetDlgItem(MyImageControl))->SetBitmap((HBITMAP)myCImage.Detach())` after calling `Load`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I see no need for the CImage new_image (as SetBitmap takes a HBITMAP which you already have through pb) and pb and pMDC must be deleted (after detaching the HBITMAP), but for the rest it seems correct.

```
CImage img1;
int dimx = 100, dimy = 100;
img1.Load(filename);
//filename = path on local system to the bitmap

CDC *screenDC = GetDC();
CDC mDC;
mDC.CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);
CBitmap b;
b.CreateCompatibleBitmap(screenDC, dimx, dimy);

CBitmap *pob = mDC.SelectObject(&b);
mDC.SetStretchBltMode(HALFTONE);
img1.StretchBlt(mDC.m_hDC, 0, 0, dimx, dimy, 0, 0, img1.GetWidth(), img1.GetHeight(), SRCCOPY);
mDC.SelectObject(pob);

m_pictureCtrl.SetBitmap((HBITMAP)b.Detach());
ReleaseDC(screenDC);
```

Of course I would put the scaling of the CImage/CBitmap into a separate function (make it reusable).

Comment: How to get the byte buffer of the scaled image ?

Comment: A really helpful comment. Thanks to your adding the 2 last lines.

Comment: A really helpful comment. Thanks to your adding the 2 last lines.

Comment: Thank you! Especially for the 3 last lines which are not found on many answers.